# PHP detecting TCP client disconnect

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, detection, disconnect

I got a TCP server up and running, which supports many client connections at the same time, together with reading and sending data. However, when client closes the connection, there is a delay on the server to detect a disconnected client.

```
// TCP socket created here
$clients = array($socket);
while (true) {
    $read = $clients; // Copy of $clients
    $write = NULL;
    $except = NULL;
    $num_changed_sockets = socket_select($read, $write, $except, NULL);
    if ($num_changed_sockets === false) {
        // ...
    } else if ($num_changed_sockets > 0) { // Something changed
        printb("In here."); // EDIT
        if (in_array($socket, $read)) { // For new connections and removing host from the $clients copy
            $newsock = socket_accept($socket);
            if ($newsock !== false) {
                printb("Client $newsock connected");
                $clients[] = $newsock;
            }
            $key = array_search($socket, $read);
            unset($read[$key]);
        }
        foreach ($read as $read_socket) { // The actual problem starts here?
            printb("Read part."); // EDIT
            $data = socket_read($read_socket, 128);
            if ($data === false) {
                printb("Client $read_socket disconnected");
                $key = array_search($read_socket, $clients);
                socket_close($clients[$key]);
                unset($clients[$key]);
                continue;
            }
       }
}
```

EDIT I:
I just added debug prints in the code. When a single client disconnects, server falls into infinite loop from `$num_changed_sockets`. Is there way to fix it?

EDIT II:
`var_dump` gives empty string after a client has disconnected.

EDIT III:
According to last edit, disconnecting the client, if `socket_read` returns an empty string seems to work. I Found a note from PHP's website:

> Note: `socket_read()` returns a zero length string ("") when there is no more data to read.

Should not this return `false`, when client disconnects?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php#105735 < maybe this comment will help you?

Comment: I want it to be based on this as `socket_select` is meant for many client connections. Of course I Could try `socket_recv` instead of  `socket_read`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php < that says, you shouldn't pass NULL to select.

Comment: "You do not need to pass every array to socket_select(). You can leave it out and use an empty array or NULL...". What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Note:
Due a limitation in the current Zend Engine it is not possible to pass a constant modifier like NULL directly as a parameter to a function which expects this parameter to be passed by reference. Instead use a temporary variable or an expression with the leftmost member being a temporary variable:
Example #1 Using NULL with socket_select()
<?php
$e = NULL;
socket_select($r, $w, $e, 0);
?>

Comment: I did it in my code above. Your comment does not fix my actual problem there is.